# How do you pass additional URL values to Django generic DeleteView?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have models.py:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now in the Detail View of a Parent I list out the children that belong to the parent.

The urls.py for this would look like

```
path('parents/<int:pk>/, views.ParentDetailView.as_view(), name='parent-detail')
```

And I'd use a django DetailView in my views.py like this

```
class ParentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Parent
```

Now in this detail view I list out the children of the parent with something like parent_detail.html in my templates

```
{{parent}}
{% for child in parent.child_set.all %}
    {{ child.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I'd like to be able to delete the child from the database from here on this page, so I'd add something like

```
{{parent}}
{% for child in parent.child_set.all %}
    {{ child.name }}
    <a href="{% url 'myapp:parent-delete-child" parent.pk child.pk %}">Delete child</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's where I'm stuck!
I would love to have something like this in my urls.py

```
path('parents/<int:pk>/', views.ParentDetailView.as_view(), name='parent-detail'),
path('parents/<int:pk>/delete_child/<int:child_pk>/', views.ParentDeleteChildView.as_view(), name='parent-delete-child')
```

But I have no idea how to send the pk and the child_pk to the generic django DeleteView?!?!?!

```
class ParentDeleteChildView(DeleteView):
    model = Child
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:parent-detail' kwargs={'pk':pk})
```

After deleting I want to go back to the parent detail page. But the success url needs to know the pk of the parent. How do I tell the generic view to delete the child that matches the child_pk and then go to the parent detail page that matches the pk? Am I better off not using the generic DeleteView?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve it using `get_success_url` in `django`.
By default `pk_url_kwarg` is set to kwarg `pk`. But in this case we have to delete child object i.e `child_pk`. so, we have to mention it by overriding `pk_url_kwarg` to `child_pk`.

```
class ParentDeleteChildView(DeleteView):
    model = Child
    pk_url_kwarg = 'child_pk'

    def get_success_url(self):
        success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:parent-detail' kwargs={'pk':self.kwargs['pk']})
        return success_url
```